# Javascript/html: How to generate random number between number A and number B?

Tags: javascript, html

We have a form with 2 fields and a button. We want on button click to output random int number (like 3, 5 or 33) which would lie between int A and int B? (no use of jQuery or anything like it is required)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Javascript Math.random

```
function randomInRange(start,end){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1) + start);
}
```

Comment: give it 33 and 44 and get 4=)

Comment: I called this function in a 1000 times for loop, all gives results in between 33 and 44.

Comment: @rella you can't get 4 as result sum of positive number and 33.
you will get at least 33 :)

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
Math.floor(a + Math.random() * (b - a))
```

The [`Math.random()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a random floating-point number in the range [0,1) — that is, between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

Comment: I think (re-reading both the question and the code carefully) the OP might want to multiply `(b + 1 - a)` not `(a - b)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like `Math.floor(Math.random()*(intB-intA +1)) + intA` ?