# JavaScript randomly selecting/returning a number from a range?

Tags: javascript, math, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript/html: How to generate random number between number A and number B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558831/javascript-html-how-to-generate-random-number-between-number-a-and-number-b)

Herren und Mensch!

Ich habbe eine question for you regardings the: Randomly returning a number between a/from the range (from -> to), using the infomous Math.round()?

How is this achiveable in the controversial JavaScript scripting language supported by major number of Web-browsers?

Comment: "Herren und Mensch" is not a valid german salutation :)

Comment: This has to be the strangest thing I've read all day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should return a random number between min and max:

```
function rangeRandom(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from + Math.floor((to-from)*Math.random())
```

will give you a random number between `from` and `to` (not inclusive for `to`).