# Random Number Generator using html and javascript not giving proper random number as answer

Tags: javascript, html

I started learning JavaScript about a week ago and now I have encountered a problem. My code is not returning proper random number as an answer. Please have a look at my code and help me out. Thanks.

```js
    function calc() {
      var min = document.getElementById('min').value;
      var max = document.getElementById('max').value;
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + max);
      document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
<table border='1px' color='black'>
  <tr>
    <td>min</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='min' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>max</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='max' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='button' onClick='calc()' value='generate' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id='random'>0</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: random() gives a no. between 0 and 1. multiplying it by (max-min) will give us a no between 0 and (max-min) and adding min to both will give a no b/w min and max.                                                                            this code is generating a random number but now i discovered that it is giving a number between 0 and (max-min) ie it is not taking +min into account :|

Comment: yes. but how to correct it.

Comment: `max` and `min` are strings, not numbers; use `parseInt` on them before beginning your computation.

Comment: _"...ie it is not taking +min into account :|"_ - it's not taking `+max` into account right?...

Comment: @War10ck `+max` is in the OP's code, but it's incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You must use [`parseInt(string,10)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611824/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix) on your `min` and `max` values before beginning your computation, or else `... + max` will concatenate strings instead of adding numbers.

As for the arithmetic, [try `var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558831/javascript-html-how-to-generate-random-number-between-number-a-and-number-b?lq=1)

```js
    function calc() {
      var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value,10);
      var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value,10);
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
      document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
<table border='1px' color='black'>
  <tr>
    <td>min</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='min' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>max</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='max' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='button' onClick='calc()' value='generate' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id='random'>0</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript code like this

```
    <script type="javascript">              
function calc(){
      var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
      var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = x;    
}                     
</script>
```